# WP/WP8 - Interactive Map Integration

Tags: .net, windows-phone-8

I would like to know if somebody know if there is possible to integrate an interactive Map in a Windows Phone/Windows Phone 8 Application.

I would like to have features like: selecting countries/ cities, zoom-in/out, move the map and so on.

Does anybody know what can I use? (some frameworks maybe?)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start by trying this Demo using `ArcGIS API` suitable for Silverlight : http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/silverlight/samples/start.htm.

Also, you can use:

- Visual Studio 2010
- Silverlight 4
- Bing Maps Silverlight Control SDK. Download Link : http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=2949

The proper steps in creating such a map are:

1. Create a new solution in Visual Studio
2. Add references to the Bing Maps Silverlight Control API
3. Create map control
4. Create Silverlight UI controls
5. Connect the map to a data source
6. Handle user input and plot map pushpins

However you can treat this as a "vector" based Interactive map.

There is also an existing tutorial for this : http://blog.credera.com/technology-insights/microsoft-solutions/building-interactive-maps-with-silverlight-and-bing-maps-2/.

Another way to do it is to use **Telerik Map Integration Control** which I think properly is what you really want: http://www.telerik.com/products/silverlight/map.aspx.

If you have any question, please ask.

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you just use the map object from Window Phone itself? It's in the .NET framework and pretty easy to use.

See here:

[Map tutorial MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207045%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Part 24 and 25 of this video tutorial should also get you started with basic functionality of the map.

[Video Tutorial (24 and 25)](http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Windows-Phone-8-Development-for-Absolute-Beginners?page=3)

Comment: Well, somehow it is useful (zoom,rotation,moving,position,location,etc). But I'm interested in selecting some countries/cities. :)

Comment: Okay, you mean like selecting France and giving it another colorbrush?

Comment: Yes, something like that.

Comment: Have you looked into map overlays? Maybe you could use an overlay when a map is clicked within a specific set of coordinates?

Comment: That means to set for each location(country,city..) a set of coordinates, which isn't very comfortable.:D If we have about 3k+ cities...

Comment: yeah, thats quite a downside. Point taken.